# ClassCastException DTO OSGI

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have three blueprint bundles (distinct jars):

- **ap-data**: contains only a class named Game.java, supposed to be used as a  DTO. It's an entity, annotated with @Entity.
- **ap-dao**: a persistence bundle that contains persistence.xml, Meta-Persistence header in OSGI manifest and imports Game.java from **ap-data**.
- **ap-service**: also imports Game.java from **ap-data** and an interface exposed by **ap-dao**, IGameDAO.java. It exposes IGameService.java also.

Realized that these bundles form layers of a module Game. Scenario:

- All bundles are deployed correct in Karaf 3.0.5 (all are 'ACTIVE').
- **ap-dao** bundle is correctly loaded as a persistence bundle, can access a configured datasource and can access EntityManager without problems. It can execute queries and I can see the results. All is fine.
- **ap-service** can inject an instance of IGameDAO with no problem. All is fine until here.
- The class Game.java (DTO) is only contained in the ap-data bundle. There is no duplicates (I checked).

Problem:

The **Game** *typed* in GameServiceImpl is loaded by the **ap-service** bundle classloader and the instances returned by the IGameDAO service are of another type since they were loaded by the **ap-dao** bundle classloader, therefore generating ClassCastException. Realize that the class is the same (app.Game.java) , supposed to be a DTO. DTOs are basic objects that I must be able to use and pass them through bundles (by services). How DTOs are treated in OSGI? How can I solve this problem?

```
// code in GameServiceImpl, from ap-service bundle
public void prettyPrintGames() {
    List<Game> games = gameDao().findAll();

    /* ClassCastException in the for-loop, since the type Game, in ap-service
     * is not the same of the instances of varible 'games', 
     * returned by the DAO service instance. This is the reason
     * of the classloader issue.
     */
    for(Game g : games){
        System.out.println(g.toString()); 
    }
}
```

Structure:

### ap-data

```
+---ap-data
|   |   pom.xml
|   |       
|   +---src
|   |   \---main
|   |       +---java
|   |       |   \---br
|   |       |       \---com
|   |       |           \---company
|   |       |               \---game
|   |       |                   \---entity
|   |       |                           Game.java
```

Bundle manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1445945039034
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_07
Built-By: user
Bundle-Description: ap-data
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ap-data
Bundle-SymbolicName: ap-data
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: br.com.company.game.entity;version="1.0.0";uses:="javax.
 persistence"
Import-Package: javax.persistence;version="[2.1,3)"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

### ap-dao

```
+---ap-dao
|   |   pom.xml
|   +---src
|   |   \---main
|   |       +---java
|   |       |   \---br
|   |       |       \---com
|   |       |           \---company
|   |       |               \---game
|   |       |                   \---dao
|   |       |                       +---api
|   |       |                       |       IGameDAO.java
|   |       |                       |       
|   |       |                       \---impl
|   |       |                               GameDAOImpl.java
|   |       |                               
|   |       \---resources
|   |           +---META-INF
|   |           |       persistence.xml
|   |           |       
|   |           \---OSGI-INF
|   |               \---blueprint
|   |                       blueprint.xml
|   |
```

Bundle Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1445945039855
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_07
Built-By: user
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml
Bundle-Description: game-module
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ap-dao
Bundle-SymbolicName: ap-dao
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: br.com.company.game.dao.api;version="1.0.0";uses:="br.co
 m.company.game.entity"
Export-Service: br.com.company.game.dao.api.IGameDAO
Import-Package: br.com.company.game.dao.api;version="[1.0,2)",br.com.com
 pany.game.entity;version="[1.0,2)",javax.persistence;version="[2.1,3)",
 org.osgi.service.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

### ap-service

```
+---ap-service
|   |   pom.xml
|   |   
|   +---src
|   |   \---main
|   |       +---java
|   |       |   \---br
|   |       |       \---com
|   |       |           \---company
|   |       |               \---game
|   |       |                   \---service
|   |       |                       +---api
|   |       |                       |       IGameService.java
|   |       |                       |       
|   |       |                       \---impl
|   |       |                               GameServiceImpl.java
|   |       |                               
|   |       \---resources
|   |           \---OSGI-INF
|   |               \---blueprint
|   |                       service.xml
|   |
```

Bundle manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1445945040469
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_07
Built-By: user
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/service.xml
Bundle-Description: game-module
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ap-service
Bundle-SymbolicName: ap-service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: br.com.company.game.service.api;version="1.0.0"
Export-Service: br.com.company.game.service.api.IGameService
Import-Package: br.com.company.game.dao.api;version="[1.0,2)",br.com.com
 pany.game.entity;version="[1.0,2)",br.com.company.game.service.api;vers
 ion="[1.0,2)",org.osgi.service.blueprint;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
Import-Service: br.com.company.game.dao.api.IGameDAO;multiple:=false
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

### Analysis:

I made some tests here in ap-dao and just realized that if I return the entities without passing through EntityManager, creating the objects hardcoded, for instance, everything works. Once I use entityManager to query the entities, the problem come back again and I get ClassCastException.

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Game> findAll() {
        return _findAllHardCoded(); // this work just fine in service layer, no ClassCastException

        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Game s").getResultList(); // if I use this, ClassCastException is generated in the service layer

    }

    protected List<Game> _findAllHardCoded() {
        List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
        games.add(new Game(Short.valueOf("1"), "Game1"));
        games.add(new Game(Short.valueOf("2"), "Game2"));
        return games;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide any help please Christian Christian Schneider?

Comment: If I were you, I would use a helper variable with type Object where ClassCastException occurs. I would debug there and check the real type of the object and compare it with the class type I want to cast to. I would check their classloaders. With that I could probably get some information like: JPA uses black magic and creates a class type at runtime or JPA caches the class type in a Map and instantiates it based on that, but somebody else restarts the bundle of Game.java and does bundle weaving...

Comment: What persistence provider do you use btw?

Comment: The class is the same, I think only classloader is different :   

java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.company.game.entity.Game cannot be cast to br.com.company.game.entity.Game
 at br.com.company.game.service.impl.GameServiceImpl.prettyPrintGames(GameServiceImpl.java:30)
 at Proxy561ddac9_3d0d_4154_ac2b_f63a1852e182.prettyPrintGames(Unknown Source)
 at Proxy63e0d3db_6f54_4231_a8b0_d20e2665a1e7.prettyPrintGames(Unknown Source)
 at br.com.company.game.rest.GameResourceImpl.prettyPrintGames(GameResourceImpl.java:15)

Comment: I'm using Hibernate as JPA Provider. The query is executed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your setup is correct then ap-data should contain the class Game and have an Export-Package for the package Game is in. The other two bundles should have an Import-Package statement for this package. In this case the class Game should only be loaded by the classloader of ap-data.

Also take care how you setup the maven bundle plugin. If you for example tell it to export a package that is contained in another bundle then it will embed it in your own bundle. So probably the easiest way is to leave it at defaults.

Things you can look for are. No package should be contained in more then one bundle. You should use Aries JPA to do the JPA access. As Balazs commented the persistence providers often do black magic inside. In combination with Aries JPA it should work in OSGi but if you use plain JPA there may be problems.

I checked the project on github. I think the problem is the location of the persistence.xml. This file should always be located in the project that contains the entity classes. Can you try to move it?

Comment: I provided the project structure above. I'll put the project on github now.

Comment: URL: https://github.com/jhnotammake202015/github/ . I'm deploying the generated KAR file (ap-kar/target) in apache karaf. I appreciate any help to make it work.

Comment: In this repository, I also put the karaf distribution with the startup features already configured.

Comment: Just to help: I made some tests here in ap-dao and just realized that if I return the entities without passing through EntityManager, creating the objects hardcoded, for instance, everything works. Once I use entityManager to query the entities, the problem come back again and I get ClassCastException. I will provide the code above in the issue. See that please!!

Comment: I edited the answer. I think I solved the problem. Can you try to move the persistence.xml to the ap-data project?

Comment: I made some tests here and realized that starting karaf with clean state (removing data folder), everything works. It appears a "cache" problem with the KAR bundles. Updating the KAR file at runtime generates the error. If I begin from clean state again, the error goes away.

Comment: Ah ok .. that is a known issue with Aries JPA 1.x. You should have look at the new 2.2.0 version. See my examples at http://www.liquid-reality.de

Comment: I got it. Christian Schneider, thank you so much for your efforts. I'll give the answer to up vote it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to Christian Schneider, as shown in comments, trying to update KAR file in runtime, which uses EntityManager in any persistence bundle, generates ClassCastException betweens bundles trying to cast entities types, what is a known issue with Aries JPA 1.x. The Aries JPA 2x is the way to go. Thanks!